# How to convert html code to "html-converted" plain text with Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4

I have, for example a table field with a html content like this:

```
<ul>
 <li>&&amp;Avalada por la Sociedad Española de Psicooncología</li>
 <li>space&nbsp;another_space:&#160;</li>
</ul>
```

And I not only want to remove html tags: I want to get the "html-translated" text, exactly this:
[image]

I can get this through: `sanitize(pm, tags:[], attributes:[])`

But if I put this into a variable i get this:

```
&&amp;Avalada por la Sociedad Española de Psicooncología
 space&nbsp;another_space:&#160;
```

[image]

The solution remains **not only** in `strip_tags` or `sanitize` or `html_safe`, because on the browser I already can see it correctly, but I want to get this text **"&&Avalada por la Sociedad Española de Psicooncología space another_space: "** to save afterwards in a XML file without html-codes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well can be people, that thinks this is a stupid situation, because anybody wants to put a "&" in a value of a xml file field... But manager orders are orders that must be met

The solution is in **content** method of Nokogiri:

```
Nokogiri::HTML("<ul><li>&&amp;Av...logía</li>
<li>space&nbsp;...ce:&#160;</li></ul>").content
```

And then use **to_sym** in the xml.builder:

```
 xml.libro(
      ISBN:"blabla",
      resumen: descripcion_libro.to_sym)
```

---

In fact I had to make magic, because I have things like this in BBDD

```
<P>&lt;iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/A3hTVX
```

yes!! this is HTML code encoded in HTML ¿?¿?, to solve this I did:

```
 descripcion_libro=sanitize(Nokogiri::HTML(Catalog.find(3190).descripcion).content, tags:[], attributes:[])

# Some invisible characters to replace
descripcion_libro.gsub!(/./){|c| (c.bytes==[194,160]  ? " " : c)}

descripcion_libro.strip!

# Replace " by ', although this not ensure than won't be html errors if in bbdd appears "<" or ">"
descripcion_libro.gsub!('"',"'")
```